# Trouble saving grid of ggplots to file

Tags: r, ggplot2, png, gridextra

I am trying and failing to save a grid of ggplots as a .png on my hard drive and would appreciate some help troubleshooting my code.

Here's an example that reproduces my error using public data on Lego Star Wars sets:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

# Load the Lego data and subset it to Lego Star Wars sets
Lego <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/seankross/lego/master/data-tidy/legosets.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
Lego.SW <- filter(Lego, Theme=="Star Wars")

# Make a list with the ggplot objects to plot
lego_plot_list = list()
lego_plot_list[[1]] = ggplot(tally(group_by(Lego.SW, Year)), aes(x=Year, y=n)) + geom_line() + theme_bw() + ylab("Number of sets released")
lego_plot_list[[2]] = ggplot(Lego.SW, aes(Pieces)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=10) + theme_bw() + ylab("Number of sets")
lego_plot_list[[3]] = ggplot(Lego.SW, aes(USD_MSRP)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=10) + theme_bw() + xlab("Price (USD)") + ylab("Number of sets")
lego_plot_list[[4]] = ggplot(Lego.SW, aes(x=Pieces, y=USD_MSRP)) + geom_point() + theme_bw() + xlab("Number of pieces") + ylab("Price")

# Make the plots
lego.grid = marrangeGrob(lego_plot_list, nrow=2, ncol=2, top="")
lego.grid  # show in terminal to make sure we're getting what we want
ggsave("legostarwars.png", lego.grid)
```

And here's the error I get at the end of that process, whether or not I previously display `lego.grid` in the terminal:

```
Error in ggsave("legostarwars.png", lego.grid) : 
  plot should be a ggplot2 plot
```

I *think* my code follows the example given in the `arrangeGrob()` documentation, and I didn't see a different solution in related questions. Apologies if I overlooked something and this is a duplicate.

In case it's relevant, here's my session info:

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.4.2     gridExtra_2.0.0 ggplot2_1.0.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.0      assertthat_0.1   digest_0.6.8     MASS_7.3-43      R6_2.1.0         plyr_1.8.3       DBI_0.3.1        gtable_0.1.2     magrittr_1.5    
[10] scales_0.2.5     stringi_0.5-5    lazyeval_0.1.10  reshape2_1.4.1   labeling_0.3     proto_0.3-10     tools_3.2.1      stringr_1.0.0    munsell_0.4.2   
[19] parallel_3.2.1   colorspace_1.2-6
```

Comment: I suspect this is a `gridExtra` version issue, because that line works fine for me. From a previous comment of yours, I think you were using version 0.9, and I'm using 2.0.

Comment: Yes, I am using 0.9.1

Comment: version 0.9.1 used a dirty trick to fool ggsave into thinking that the combined graphic was a ggplot; I've removed this workaround in version 2.0, but unfortunately it brings some inconvenience for this transition period before the next ggplot2 update fixes it.

Comment: @baptiste: any idea when that fix might come? (Trying to figure out whether I need to rewrite my broken ggsave + marrangeGrob code with base device functions) Thanks!

Comment: @janattack no idea, sorry; you could ask ggplot2 developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ggsave` is not mandatory for the results, an alternative would be using the function `png`, it will yield similar (if not the same) results via this code:

```
png('legostarwars.png')
lego.grid
dev.off()
```

Comment: That works, thank you. Funny, I'm used to using base R's plotting functions and usually do this but didn't think to do it here.

Answer (score 2):

If you're saving to a single png file, you probably don't mean to use `marrangeGrob()` (**m**ultiple pages), but `arrangeGrob()`.
The error you see is due to a check in `ggplot2::ggsave`, which should disappear in the next release. In the meantime you can either call `png()` explicitly, or install the dev version of ggplot2.

Answer (score 1):

Using the devel version of `dplyr/ggplot2` in `R 3.2.2`, it worked for me.

```
lego.grid <- marrangeGrob(lego_plot_list, nrow=2, ncol=2, top="")
grid.newpage()#from @baptiste's comments
ggsave("legostarwars.png", lego.grid)
#Saving 7 x 6.99 in image
```

[image]

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] lazyeval_0.1.10.9000 gridExtra_2.0.0      ggplot2_1.0.1.9003  
[4] data.table_1.9.5     dplyr_0.4.3.9000     overflow_0.2-1      
[7] stringr_1.0.0        reshape2_1.4.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.0      assertthat_0.1   chron_2.3-45     plyr_1.8.2      
 [5] R6_2.0.1         gtable_0.1.2     DBI_0.3.1        magrittr_1.5    
 [9] scales_0.3.0     stringi_0.5-1    labeling_0.3     tools_3.2.2     
[13] munsell_0.4.2    parallel_3.2.2   colorspace_1.2-6
```

Comment: When I run the first of those two lines, I get this error: `Error: nrow * ncol >= n is not TRUE`.

Comment: @ulfelder I am using `R 3.2.2`, `gridExtra_0.9.1`,  `dplyr_0.4.1.9000` and `ggplot2_1.0.1`

Comment: Okay, so maybe it's a `gridExtra` version issue. I'm using 2.0 there. I'm also using `R 3.2.1`, but that seems less likely to be the source of the hitch.

Comment: @ulfelder It works for me.  I thought to post this as you were asking specifically for a ggsave solution.  I will delete the post.

Comment: `plot.new()` is unnecessary (and for grid graphics it would be `grid.newpage`)

Comment: @baptiste Thanks, I tried to use it without `plot.new`,  I got the error `Error: No graphics device is open. Please supply height and width`
 then I had to specify the width..  The `grid.newpage()` worked